# Different kinds of quotation marks on the same document

Tags: lyx, punctuation

I've just generated a pdf and I got the following output.

[image]

As you can see the quotation marks differ.

I am using Lyx if that's important, and in that environment I also get the same thing.

[image]

I notice that at the moment I can only type those quotation marks that look like two ' and I have no clue why that is. Any ideas?

`\item The Ocean - \textquotedbl{}Precambrian\textquotedbl{}
\item The Ocean \textendash{} \textquotedblleft Aeolian\textquotedblright{}`

Comment: What is your LyX version? What does it say under Document > Settings > Language? What keyboard layout do you use?

Comment: Would you add a minimal example of what you wrote on the tex file? Just a small document starting with `\documentclass{...}` ending with  `\end{document}` that reproduces your output.

Comment: @scottkosty Lyx version: 2.2.2. Language: English.; Quote style: (first style). I am using a portuguese keyboard. From what I understand, this is happening because parts of the file were written long ago (possibly with another computer, etc...). But anyway I don't get why it doesn't get automatically uniform. I already run the quick&search thing to get it uniform. I was just curious to understand more about this.

Comment: @santimirandarp I'm silly, I should have looked at the source code. Thank you. I've edited my question and I guess now everything is clear...

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how it happened. LyX will do its best not to change old documents. In LyX 2.3.0 there are some bug fixes for quotations, but I think those will only help in the case you start a completely new document: https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX.NewInLyX23#quotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item The Ocean \textendash{} \textquotedblleft{}Precambrian\textquotedblright{}
\item The Ocean \textendash{} \textquotedblleft{}Aeolian\textquotedblright{}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

It will produce:

[image: img]